# Android PreferenceActivity - Switches back to default

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I'm developing an app that sends messages depending of the categories you are subscribed.

To do so, I have implemented a `PreferenceActivity` where I add dynamically a `SwitchPreference` for each category as showed at the picture below.

[image: snapshot android PreferenceActivity]

The problem is that when I change the switches status, scroll down and then scroll up they go back to default status by their own.

Did anybody have the same problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632215/preference-items-being-automatically-re-set

Comment: thanks to @don-chakkappan, you comment helped me to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is caused by an [Android bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26194) for earlier versions of android 5 Lollipop.

If you are developing for Android 4.X or below, you have two options:

1 - Develop a custom `SwitchPreference`

2 - Use `Checkboxes` instead.

To do so, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906338/android-switchpreferences-change-together-in-preferenceactivity) question related.